Force Ending an MDT Task Sequence
I'm running into this problem where it doesn't seem like the task sequence is ending. It just hangs at the last step. Does anyone know how to force end a task sequence?
I haven't been able to find anything on this topic after searching for quite a while. My colleague tried a generic cmd command task to try and end it but it still hung.
